# smtplib times out connecting to AWS SES despite receiving a 220 service ready

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, amazon-ses, smtplib

I am attempting to send an email with AWS SES using a Dockerized Python program. When I try to connect to SES by making an [`SMTP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP) instance, the program hangs and times out.

To reproduce:

1. Start the Python 3.6.8 REPL
2. Import `smtplib`

```py
>>> import smtplib
```

3. Try to connect to SES, and observe how the statement hangs.

```py
>>> conn = smtplib.SMTP(host='email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=25)
# terminal hangs for 10 seconds
```

4. Try using the connection, which fails.

```py
>>> conn.noop()
(451, b'4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.')
>>> conn.noop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 514, in noop
    return self.docmd("noop")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 421, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Unsurprisingly, step (3) sends a DNS query for the SES endpoint, and then connects; the SES endpoint responds with `220 service ready` nearly instantaneously. No traffic is exchanged until 10 seconds later, when SES closes the connection with `451 timeout waiting for client`. The statement completes, and then runs the rest of my program which, of course, doesn't work.

For context, the rest of my script is as follows:

```py
smtp_host = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
smtp_port = 25
smtp_proto = 'tls'

with smtplib.SMTP(host=smtp_host, port=smtp_port) as connection:
    try:
        ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23 if smtp_proto == 'ssl' else ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        connection.starttls(context=ctx)
        connection.ehlo()

        connection.login(smtp_user, smtp_pass)

        connection.send_message(from_addr=sender, to_addrs=recipients, msg=message)
    except smtplib.SMTPHeloError as e:
        print(f"SMTP HELO Failed: {e}")
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError as e:
        print(f"SMTP AUTH Failed: {e}")
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print(f"Failed to send email: {e}")
```

I've attempted to connect on ports 25, 587, 2587, and 465. I've done the same with the [`SMTP_SSL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) object instead, as well as changing the context in the `starttls` call to various SSL / TLS versions (the SSL versions result in [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19390267/14199334) - but this isn't relevant since I can't get to this portion of the script, anyway).

I've tested my connection to SES according to [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-smtp.html). I've also tried parts of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087158/amazon-ses-smtp-python-usage#12358203) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160886/how-to-send-smtp-email-for-office365-with-python-using-tls-ssl) SO post (as well as a myriad of others that are lost in my browser history).

To actually send emails, I need to [`connect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.connect) a second time. Connecting, then waiting for a timeout, then connecting again, seems wrong. What is the **proper** way to do this?

Comment: same issue here